# What is the conceptual difference between bin and gen?

Tags: bazel

For ordinary rules, output gets written in the `bin` dictionary. For e.g. `genrule`s output is written to `genfiles` directory. While this is not surprising given the name of the latter name, I wonder why there is a and what is the conceptual difference.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a particularly good reason (and you can actually write genrules' output to bin with the `output_to_bindir` attribute and put Skylark outputs anywhere you want).

It's just historical.  There are actually a couple of other output directories like those (e.g., testlogs, include), they're just the most common.